# Reading XML that is saved as text from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

this is what my query looks like:

```
select top 5   cast(content_html as xml) as [prodxml],
prodxml.value('data(ClassTemplate[1]', 'nvarchar(max) ') as prod2
from content 
where 
end_date >= getdate()
and folder_id != 71682
```

and i keep getting:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "prodxml" or the user-defined function or aggregate "prodxml.value", or the name is ambiguous.
```

what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i can't query prod1 directly, how else can i find all records that have "Other" as the Class Template?

You can't reference a column alias in another column of the same SELECT statement - use:

```
SELECT TOP 5   
       CAST(t.content_html AS XML).value('(/root/ClassTemplate)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') AS prod2
  FROM CONTENT t
 WHERE t.end_date >= getdate()
   AND t.folder_id != 71682
```

If you want to filter out based on the prod2 value in the WHERE clause - use:

```
  FROM CONTENT t
 WHERE CAST(t.content_html AS XML).value('(/root/ClassTemplate)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') = 'Other'
   AND t.end_date >= getdate()
   AND t.folder_id != 71682
```

Comment: select top 5  cast(content_html as xml).value('data(ClassTemplate[1]', 'nvarchar(500)) ') as prod1
from content 
where content_status = 'A' and content_type=3333
and end_date >= getdate()
and folder_id != 71682 
and i am now getting: The data type 'nvarchar(500)) ' used in the VALUE method is invalid.

Comment: @Tanya Xrum: There's a typo in what you posted - `'nvarchar(500))` should be `nvarchar(500)`

Comment: thanks, now i get 5 nulls..i should be getting the values of the "ClassTemplate" node, right?

Comment: There's a missing close bracket I think? `'data(ClassTemplate[1]'` should be  `'data(ClassTemplate[1])'`

Comment: @Tanya Xrum: The query is looking for a `data(ClassTemplate` node - can you post a sample of the XML?

Comment: <root><ClassTemplate>Other</ClassTemplate>  <Default><ClassTitle>test class</ClassTitle>  <ClassDescription>description</ClassDescription>  <ClassType_>Demonstration</ClassType_>  <Location>Bethesda</Location>  <Instructor>dneal@lacademie.com</Instructor>  <Menu>menu </Menu>  <StartDate>2010-10-17</StartDate>  <EndHours>01</EndHours>  <EndMinutes>00</EndMinutes>  <StartTime>AM</StartTime>  <EndDate>2010-11-06</EndDate>  <StartHours>01</StartHours>  <StartMinutes>00</StartMinutes>  <EndTime>AM</EndTime>  <ClassID></ClassID>  </Default>  </root>

Comment: hm, if i can't query prod1 directly, how else can i find all records that have "Other" as the Class Template?

Comment: @Tanya Xrum: I don't see how, based on the sample you provided - I tested on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: thanks! :) now i'm getting XML parsing: line 1, character 88, illegal name character, but i believe it's because i have some "&" in my code.  Thanks again!!!