# How to obtain a XML column which is part of a table field in SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I'm using Yellowfin which connects to a SQL 2012 database.  Within a table there is a column called EnteredXML which contains full XML from a web submission, so a sub table of XML type within the column.  From the XML column I want to obtain a specific value from the column called CoverRateSelection.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    MemberNo, 
    TransTypeID, 
    EnteredXML.value('(/MembershipApplication/Cover/CoverRateSelection/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
FROM 
    V204241Webtransactions
WHERE 
    TransTypeID = 'MemAp'
```

The response I get from this is

> SQL statement is invalid.

The error message returned from the database was:

> Cannot find either column "EnteredXML" or the user-defined function or aggregate "EnteredXML.value", or the name is ambiguous.

the table looks like this:

[image]

The XML looks like this (I've removed personal info):

[image]

I got this far using other posts at stackoverflow:

[how-to-get-a-particular-attribute-from-xml-element-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561102/how-to-get-a-particular-attribute-from-xml-element-in-sql-server)

[extracting-attributes-from-xml-fields-in-sql-server-2008-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846990/extracting-attributes-from-xml-fields-in-sql-server-2008-table)

[reading-xml-that-is-saved-as-text-from-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001141/reading-xml-that-is-saved-as-text-from-sql)

but I'm now a bit lost and confused.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Are you 100% sure on the column name, because that's the most obvious problem that the error message is trying to steer you towards.

Comment: What is the type of `EnteredXML` ? It must be XML to accept  the xml function  `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Serg I realised although the values were XML it was infact a Text field, therefore I used the Substring Method to obtain the data:

```
SELECT 
    MemberNo, 
    TransTypeID, 
    SUBSTRING(EnteredXML, (CHARINDEX('<CoverRateSelection>', EnteredXML)+ 20), (CHARINDEX('</CoverRateSelection>', EnteredXML) - (CHARINDEX('<CoverRateSelection>', EnteredXML)) As JoinCover
FROM 
    V204241Webtransactions
WHERE 
    TransTypeID = 'MemAp'
```

If you run this type of command however it also brings in the XML tag.  I've tried adding a value to the length section of the substring:

`((CHARINDEX('</CoverRateSelection>', EnteredXML)-20) - (CHARINDEX('<CoverRateSelection>', EnteredXML)`

but it returns no values and says the SQL is invalid, despite the SQL test saying it is valid.  I believe this is an issue with the program rather than not the SQL.